# Using the Facebook Graph API (v2.0), how can I get only the notes published on the page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

**I have a page facebook that contain some articles, a would to get them but when I do :**

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/1432545087007695/notes?access_token=319440784873296|871VGrd1FxUDLTDeRMpfm0ndHxE`

**I have this result :**

```
    {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#12) notes API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 12
   }
}
```

**And when I do :**

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/1432545087007695/feed?access_token=319440784873296|871VGrd1FxUDLTDeRMpfm0ndHxE`

I **receive all the information about the page :**

```
    {
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1432545087007695_1433265710268966",
         "from": {
            "category": "Community",
            "name": "Bonjour",
            "id": "1432545087007695"
         },
         "picture": "https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/s130x130/1521536_1433265766935627_9164966378403324602_n.jpg",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/notes/bonjour/hello/1433265710268966",
         "name": "hello",
         "description": "deprecateddeprecateddeprecateddeprecateddeprecateddeprecateddeprecateddeprecateddeprecateddeprecated\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",
         "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yY/r/1gBp2bDGEuh.gif",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "link",
         "status_type": "created_note",
         "application": {
            "name": "Notes",
            "id": "2347471856"
         },
         "created_time": "2014-06-11T11:20:52+0000",
         "updated_time": "2014-06-11T11:20:52+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1432545087007695_1433263763602494",
         "from": {
            "category": "Community",
            "name": "Bonjour",
            "id": "1432545087007695"
         },
         "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-0/10325164_1433263880269149_978779895298362170_s.png",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/notes/bonjour/62511111111111111111111/1433263763602494",
         "name": "62511111111111111111111",
         "description": "1222222222222222223649819641964194419541584158145141",
         "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yY/r/1gBp2bDGEuh.gif",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "link",
         "status_type": "created_note",
         "application": {
            "name": "Notes",
            "id": "2347471856"
         },
         "created_time": "2014-06-11T11:13:52+0000",
         "updated_time": "2014-06-11T11:13:52+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "1432487507014191",
                  "name": "Chaimae Orbit"
               }
            ],
            "paging": {
               "cursors": {
                  "after": "MTQzMjQ4NzUwNzAxNDE5MQ==",
                  "before": "MTQzMjQ4NzUwNzAxNDE5MQ=="
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "id": "1432545087007695_1433228996939304",
         "from": {
            "category": "Community",
            "name": "Bonjour",
            "id": "1432545087007695"
         },
         "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t1.0-0/10390156_1433229026939301_5536116692037351754_s.png",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/notes/bonjour/trytrytr/1433228996939304",
         "name": "trytrytr",
         "description": "ytryrtyrty\n",
         "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yY/r/1gBp2bDGEuh.gif",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "link",
         "status_type": "created_note",
         "application": {
            "name": "Notes",
            "id": "2347471856"
         },
         "created_time": "2014-06-11T09:26:25+0000",
         "updated_time": "2014-06-11T09:26:25+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1432545087007695_1433228876939316",
         "from": {
            "category": "Community",
            "name": "Bonjour",
            "id": "1432545087007695"
         },
         "message": "fjuuyktiy",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "status",
         "status_type": "mobile_status_update",
         "created_time": "2014-06-11T09:25:35+0000",
         "updated_time": "2014-06-11T09:25:35+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1432545087007695_1432929136969290",
         "from": {
            "category": "Community",
            "name": "Bonjour",
            "id": "1432545087007695"
         },
         "story": "Bonjour updated their cover photo.",
         "story_tags": {
            "0": [
               {
                  "id": "1432545087007695",
                  "name": "Bonjour",
                  "offset": 0,
                  "length": 7,
                  "type": "page"
               }
            ]
         },
         "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t1.0-0/10303790_1432929123635958_3561739667982482211_s.png",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/1432545087007695/photos/a.1432929133635957.1073741827.1432545087007695/1432929123635958/?type=1&relevant_count=1",
         "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "photo",
         "object_id": "1432929123635958",
         "created_time": "2014-06-10T08:22:51+0000",
         "updated_time": "2014-06-10T08:22:51+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1432545087007695_1432656033663267",
         "from": {
            "category": "Community",
            "name": "Bonjour",
            "id": "1432545087007695"
         },
         "message": "Nouvaut\u00e9",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "status",
         "status_type": "mobile_status_update",
         "created_time": "2014-06-09T08:49:14+0000",
         "updated_time": "2014-06-09T08:49:14+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1432545087007695_1432545103674360",
         "from": {
            "category": "Community",
            "name": "Bonjour",
            "id": "1432545087007695"
         },
         "story": "Bonjour joined Facebook.",
         "story_tags": {
            "0": [
               {
                  "id": "1432545087007695",
                  "name": "Bonjour",
                  "offset": 0,
                  "length": 7,
                  "type": "page"
               }
            ]
         },
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "status",
         "application": {
            "name": "Reviews",
            "id": "6261817190"
         },
         "created_time": "2014-06-08T21:42:17+0000",
         "updated_time": "2014-06-08T21:42:17+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/1432545087007695/feed?access_token=319440784873296|871VGrd1FxUDLTDeRMpfm0ndHxE&limit=25&since=1402485652&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/1432545087007695/feed?access_token=319440784873296|871VGrd1FxUDLTDeRMpfm0ndHxE&limit=25&until=1402263736"
   }
}
```

**It's prove that I can communicate with my page, but how canI get only the notes?**

Comment: As the error messages say. The notes API is deprecated. So you can't get notes

Comment: yes this is the error message, so, no Solution?

Comment: No you can't get notes

Comment: this error is annoying because it can happen on other endpoints that aren't parts of the "notes API," e.g. `/comments`, i'm guessing because one of the ids i pass in the `ids` param is a note.

Answer (score 0):

We could find these notes that have "applications" property, and the "applications" has "name" property that called "Notes". We can identify the notes by this condition.

Comment: Are you sure you have then ALL notes covered being created ? Because the problem with this approach is, that the note creation should have been "recently". If you want to have "all notes" you will have to go 34023304 days back in the past to make sure you get them all ? I assume this is the only last resort you have, before notes totally dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the notes from Feed end point.

Get the feed.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/YOURPAGEID/feed?access_token=TOKEN&limit=250

Find your note on your feed and use its ID.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/FEED_ID_(NOTE_ID)/?access_token=TOKEN&limit=250&fields=attachments

Comment: I'm trying to get my notes with its formatting but not success so far. I can only get it without formatting.

Answer (score -2):

We could find these notes that have "applications" property, and the "applications" has "name" property that called "Notes".
we can identify the notes by this condition.

By PHPthinking.

The details:
http://www.phpthinking.com/archives/306

Comment: So instead of answering the question here, you answered it on your website?